# F1 score for a Random Forest model

Tags: random-forest, h2o

I have built a Random Forest model (H2O library) and then checked its accuracy on some test data. I would like to use the F1 score as a measure of the success of the model. However, I cannot find in the documentation a way to retrieve it.

I know that it is possible as this appears [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45404116/what-do-the-two-numbers-for-accuracy-precision-f1-etc-mean)

```
performance = best_nn.model_performance(test_data = test)
F1        = performance.F1()
```

However, in my case, for some reason,  performance does not have F1 as a method. 
What is wrong, and how is it possible to retreive it?

Environment:

```
H2O cluster uptime: 7 mins 29 secs
H2O cluster timezone:   Asia/Jerusalem
H2O data parsing timezone:  UTC
H2O cluster version:    3.22.0.2
H2O cluster version age:    10 days
H2O cluster name:   H2O_from_python_user_24aghd
H2O cluster total nodes:    1
H2O cluster free memory:    894 Mb
H2O cluster total cores:    4
H2O cluster allowed cores:  4
H2O cluster status: locked, healthy
H2O connection url: http://localhost:54321
H2O connection proxy:   None
H2O internal security:  False
H2O API Extensions: Algos, AutoML, Core V3, Core V4
Python version: 2.7.15 final
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that I have found the reason, and it is rather a simple one:

F1 is appropriate only for models which have two possible classes as the response variable. Mine had more.

So, H2O did not suggest the metric.

Comment: Correct, F1 is then not defined. You need to use other metrics, such as e.g. logloss.